# Storing next word of sentence in a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am doing code on anagrams in Java. I have checked some codes which ask user to enter two strings and compare them.

What I have to do is check all anagrams in a single sentence in sequence of occurrence. So I want to take "next word" of sentence in string 2 after storing first in string 1 and apply anagrams logic.
I want know how to search for next word in user entered string and store it in variable?

I have tried following code

```
public class anagram2 {

        boolean check(String s1,String s2)
        {
            char a1[]= s1.toCharArray();

            char a2[]= s2.toCharArray();

            int []index1= new int[26];

            int []index2= new int[26];

            int i = 0;

            for(i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
            {
                index1[a1[i]-'a']++;

            }
            for(i=0;i<a2.length;i++)
            {
                index2[a2[i]-'a']++;

            }
            for(i=0;i<26;i++)
            {
                if(index1[i]!=index2[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you tagging a java question with C++?

Comment: Have you thought about using the java split functionality to get the words out of a sentence?

Comment: thats a mistake...i intended to say that suggestions would be accepted in c++ also...

Comment: C++ and Java are two very different languages with very different libraries / runtimes. If you are writing this specifically in Java a C++ solution is not likely going to be easily convertible.

Comment: thanks captain and i know the fact...but frankly i came across anagrams for first time and so a bit confused about using effective language...when i googled i got similar entries in c++ also so i mentioned that...

Comment: The first thing you should do is read through all the available function of the String class, in the documentation.

Comment: Provide one example of your input sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `String.split` method to break the string into words and then use your anagram finding logic on each word.

```
String sentence = "Duck duck go";
String[] words = sentence.split(" "); //access first word with words[0], second with words[1], etc.
```

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: hello sushain...

i tried the same but its not giving correct result...when i am using words[0] its displaying full sentence but not first word...and when i enter words[1] it displays arrayindexoutofbound exception...solution pls!!!

Comment: @user2657701 what is your test sentence?

Comment: hello sushain...its done..i was doing mistake by giving extra space in split(" ") function between two quotes!!

thanks a lot!

Comment: @anubhava and sushain sir...i have implemented this and got correct...yet not achieving what i want...will you see my question and help me to crack it appropriately?

Comment: @sarvesh1465 what are you still having trouble with? for a language agnostic anagram logic, a google search will probably lead you in the right direction

Comment: @sushain sir...sir if you dont mind can i have your email id?...so that i will send you my sample input and sample output image...pls